Propagation of Partial Coherence in Image Formulation from Hopkins Model
I have been reading the paper `The concept of partial coherence in optics by Dr. Hopkins. The paper is about using the concept of partial coherence to describe image formation. I got some confusion when I read the section on propagation of partial coherence. There are in general two cases for propagation: propagation from surface to surface and propagation from entrance pupil to exit pupil.
The first question comes from the discussion of propagation from surface $S$ to surface $T$. I have concluded the conclusion into the following theorem:
Let $\Sigma$ be a source. Let $S$ be a plane on which for any $\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y} \in S$, $\gamma\left(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}\right)$ is the partial coherence between $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$. Let $T$ be another plane away from $S$ and $\boldsymbol{z}, \boldsymbol{w} \in T$. Also, let $I$ be the field of intensity from $\Sigma$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\gamma\left(\boldsymbol{z}, \boldsymbol{w}\right) = \frac{k^{2}}{4 \pi^{2} \sqrt{I\left(\boldsymbol{z}\right) I\left(\boldsymbol{w}\right)}} \int_{S} \int_{S} \frac{\sqrt{I\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) I\left(\boldsymbol{y}\right)}\gamma\left(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}\right)}{r\left(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{z}\right) r\left(\boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{w}\right)} \exp{\left(ik\left(r\left(\boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{w}\right) - r\left(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{z}\right)\right)\right)} \mathrm{d}S\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) \mathrm{d}S\left(\boldsymbol{y}\right).
\end{equation*}
The proof for this conclusion is quite technically straight-forward, except for a statement the author assumed at the very start. Again, I have reformulated his statement using my own symbolic system:
Let $\boldsymbol{v} \in \Sigma$. Then we have
\begin{equation*}
u\left(\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{z}\right) = \frac{ik}{2 \pi} \int_{S} u\left(\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{x}}\right) \frac{\exp{\left(-i k r\left(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{z}\right)\right)}}{r\left(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{z}\right)} \mathrm{d}S\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
u\left(\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{w}\right) = \frac{ik}{2 \pi} \int_{S} u\left(\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{y}}\right) \frac{\exp{\left(-i k r\left(\boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{w}\right)\right)}}{r\left(\boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{w}\right)} \mathrm{d}S\left(\boldsymbol{y}\right),
\end{equation*}
where $u\left(\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{x}\right)$ is the influence from $\boldsymbol{v}$ (source) to $\boldsymbol{x}$ (evaluation point). I am confused how we get the $\frac{ik}{2\pi}$ factor. What I can think of for this formulation is green's second identity: given the field on a surface, how to get the influence for a different surface. Does anyone have a clue about this assumption?

I will probably ask the second question on a different post.
